# How to find the Value for $N$, in proving that the sequence ${\frac{3^{n+2}}{5^n}}$ has a limit 0.

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $n > N$, then $\lvert\frac{3^{n+2}}{5^n}-0\rvert$ $< \epsilon $

$\iff$ if $n > N$, then $\lvert\frac{3^{n+2}}{5^n}\rvert$ $< \epsilon $

$\iff$ if $n > N$, then $\lvert\frac{3^n\cdot3^2}{5^n}\rvert$ $< \epsilon $

$\iff$ if $n > N$, then $\lvert\frac{9\cdot3^n}{5^n}\rvert$ $< \epsilon $

$\iff$ if $n > N$, then $9(\frac{3^n}{5^n})$ $< \epsilon $

$\iff$ if $n > N$, then  $(\frac{3^n}{5^n})$ $< \frac{\epsilon}{9} $

$\iff$ if $n > N$, then  $(\frac{3}{5})^n$ $< \frac{\epsilon}{9} $

$\iff$ if $n > N$, then $\ln((\frac{3}{5})^n) <\ln(\frac{\epsilon}{9}) $

$\iff$ if $n > N$, then $n\ln(\frac{3}{5}) <\ln(\frac{\epsilon}{9}) $

??

I'm Stuck here, I am supposed to find the value for $N$, where $n>N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-n\ln (\frac 5 3)<\ln (\frac {\epsilon} 9)$ or $n > -\ln (\frac {\epsilon} 9)/\ln (\frac 5 3) $. [What you have to note is that $\ln (\frac {\epsilon} 9) <0$ for $0 <\epsilon <9$ and $\ln (\frac 5 3) >0$]. So any $N > -\ln (\frac {\epsilon} 9)/\ln (\frac 5 3) $ will do.

Comment: just a question, why it became $-n\ln{\frac{5}{3}}<\ln{\frac{\epsilon}{9}}$ ?

Comment: $\ln x=-\ln (\frac 1  x)$. Since $\frac  3 5 <1$ we have $\ln (\frac  35) <0$ and when you multiply an inequality by  a negative number the inequality sign changes. So you have to keep track of which logarithms are positive and which are negative. I switched from $\ln (\frac  35) $ to $\ln (\frac  5 3)$ to make the logarithm positive. @Benny

Comment: Ohhhhh I see, Thank you very Much for this!!!